# Issue mixing CAAnimation with View Animation in UIViewController transition

Tags: ios, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I'm trying a crossover animation (in my example a custom `UIViewController` transition). The idea, is once a cell in a `UICollectionView` is selected on *viewControllerA*, a *viewControllerB* is added with an alpha fade-in, and the view *viewControllerA* containing the `UICollectionView` zooms in on the cell.

Similarly when *viewControllerB* is popped, the *viewControllerA* view should zoom out again, whilst the view from *viewControllerB* should alpha fade-out.

Since this matters an animation both on `UIView` properties and `CALayer` properties I'm mixing Core Animation with View Animation (like said in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW12)). Both the view from *viewControllerB* and the view from *viewControllerA* are subviews of a container view.

The code is as follows:

```
if (_operation == ContentViewControllerOperationPush)
{
    [[toViewController view] setAlpha:0.0f];
}
else
{
    [[fromViewController view] setAlpha:1.0f];
}

id animations = ^
{
    CABasicAnimation *layerTransformAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];

    [layerTransformAnimation setDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext]];

    CGFloat topLayoutGuideHeight = [toViewController topLayoutGuide].length;

    CGFloat xScale = movieWidth / _transitionRect.size.width;
    CGFloat yScale = movieHeight / _transitionRect.size.height;

    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, -[[fromViewController view] bounds].origin.x, -[[fromViewController view] bounds].origin.y, 1);
    transform = CATransform3DScale(transform, xScale, yScale, 1.0f);
    transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, -_transitionRect.origin.x, -_transitionRect.origin.y + topLayoutGuideHeight, 1.0f);

    if (_operation == ContentViewControllerOperationPush)
    {
        [layerTransformAnimation setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity]];
        [layerTransformAnimation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform]];

        [[[fromViewController view] layer] addAnimation:layerTransformAnimation forKey:@"layerTransformAnimation"];

        [[toViewController view] setAlpha:1.0f];
    }
    else
    {
        [layerTransformAnimation setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform]];
        [layerTransformAnimation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity]];

        [[[toViewController view] layer] addAnimation:layerTransformAnimation forKey:@"layerTransformAnimation"];

        [[fromViewController view] setAlpha:0.0f];
    }
};

id completion = ^(BOOL finished)
{
    [transitionContext completeTransition:![transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]];
};

[UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:animations completion:completion];
```

The zoom animation works perfectly, however the alpha fade-in/out does not in this particular case, it just pops the alpha to 1.0f at the end of the push animation (and to 0.0f at the beginning of the pop animation).

(Note that when I animate the alpha of *viewControllerA* instead of *viewControllerB* when pushing *viewControllerB*, the fade does work.)

**Why is this happening?**

Comment: did you try setting the layer opacity instead of the view alpha ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the `.transform` property on the views?  I've used it to create all sorts of zoom/fade/stretch/flip transitions, and it can be used with `[UIView animateWithDuration:]`.

If you insist on using layers, be aware that `animateWithDuration:` does NOT use `CALayer` animation under the covers and as a result will always be at least a couple frames off of the other animation.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue, and option `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent` worked for me.